# Why is the limit superior defined as an infimum?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this definition of limit superior and limit inferior, and it is confusing to me since I don't understand why the limit superior is defined as an infimum and vice versa. I'd like to know the motivation behind this definition, thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is the same as the limit of $a_N^+$, actually, because $a_N^+$ is a (perhaps nonstrictly) decreasing sequence (since you're taking the suprema as you delete elements, so the supremum may drop if the element you just deleted was the maximum).

Comment: Have you see, or worked through, any examples, in order to understand how the definition works in practice?

Answer (score 1):

> **Proposition :** If $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n.$$

In particular, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence, the sequence $(y_n)$ defined by $$y_n=\sup_{k\geq n}x_k,$$
is a decreasing sequence. Therefore, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n:=\lim_{n\to \infty }y_n\underset{\text{prop.}}{=}\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}y_n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{k\geq n}x_k.$$

Similarly, you have that $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }x_n=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\inf_{k\geq n}x_k.$$

---

**Remark :** The sequence $(y_n)$ I defined correspond to the sequence $(x_n^+)$ you defined in your original question. I didn't use this notation, because $x_n^+$ can be confused with $x_n\vee 0:=\max\{x_n,0\}$, which is strongly used in the litterature. So, to avoid this confusion, I preferred to define the sequence $(y_n)$.